# TestNG: @BeforeClass failure causes other @Factory instances to be skipped

Tags: testng, factory

Suppose I have a `@Factory` and `@DataProvider`, which returns three test instances (of the same class or different).  My test is also `group-by-instance` enabled.  Now, suppose that the second test instance executed (which is not necessarily the second test instance created - why?) has a `@BeforeClass` that fails.  Why is the third instance (untouched since test initialization) skipped entirely rather than executed?  Aren't the three test instances supposed to be fully independent?

If this is by design, is there a way to have a @Before method that is "instance-level"?

Comment: Is this @BeforeClass in a base class shared by all test instances?

Comment: I've seen it happen where the @BeforeClass method is in a superclass of the test class and in the test class itself.  The methods in question are **not** static.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. I thought `@BeforeClass` was executed only once before the test began. However, `@BeforeClass` is executed between instances the way you want it to. Personally, I had been managing my `WebDriver` incorrectly, and my second instance was failing because of the initialization causing the third instance to be skipped. Other interim solutions I tried but were probably not best practice was to use `dependsOnGroups` or `dependsOnMethods` to control the flow of your test instances.